# Android EditText noSuggestions with enter key on soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, custom-keyboard

Hi all :) A few time ago i wanted to do edittext with noSuggestions and multiLine with enter key. The problem was that, when i set:

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

then I had no suggesions, but enter key was transformed to "DONE" action. So i start combining many imeOptions and inputType and finally get this:

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textMultiLine"  
android:imeOptions="flagNoEnterAction"
```

It's weird, but when you set textNoSuggestion with flagNoEnterAction, then you will see Enter key on soft keyboard, but enter will work as SPACE button. Then you must add textMultiline and it should work good :)

Hope it helps someone!